# If $X,Y,Z$ are PAIRWISE independent (i.e. only $X,Y$ and $Y,Z$ and $X,Z$ are) , does this imply that $X$ and $(Y,Z)$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

This question came to my mind when I was reading a theorem on Poisson Processes stating that the sum of two independent Poisson processes, $X_t$ and $Y_t$ is a Poisson process. In the proof, one has to show that $X_t + Y_t$ has independent increments, and in order to prove this one must show the question I posed.
Is it true? Are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Try $(X,Y,Z)$ uniform on $\{(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1)(0,1,1)\}$.

Comment: I am not concerned to prove that they are not mutually independent. I just need in the theorem to deduce in some way that X is independent of Y+Z, or maybe of the vector (Y,Z). otherwise I cannot see how the proof of the theorem can be continued.